# Folder shown as executable

Tags: filesystem, files, directory

I copied the content of a USB stick in a folder into an NTFS drive, and everything seemed right (the folder was accessible, etc.).

But today, when I wanted to access this folder, the folder's icon turned to an executable (WIN) icon, and I can't access it (even using the terminal, the folder is recognized as a file). I can't see the file's size or do anything with it.

Thank you in advance ! (I hope I solve this in the commi

Comment: Please add a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

do you have windows on this computer or  just you have Ubuntu?
some windows viruses generates .exe files with name of folders in a directory. so it is a trick to make users to double click on them. be sure your real files are safe. so open terminal (type terminal in dash)
and follow these commands:

```
sudo su -
```

and type your password, then

```
cd /home/<your account name>/<directory of your files>/
```

then change permision of all file and folders in this directory with this command:

```
chmod 777 -R .
```

also you can see this file size with following command:

```
du -hs .
```

if it is OK (if it shows correct size). then remove .exe from end of file name by right click on them and rename it. i think it will solve this problem.